# Wordpress reach CSS file in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I have a script for a demo website that replaces a CSS file with another for different colors. It works perfectly on local, but I couldn't make it work online.

The part of the code on local that I believe is not working online is :

```
if (color == "b9e0e9") {
  switcher_link.attr('href',"http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme1/css/blue-theme.css");
  var atrrHref = switcher_link.attr('href');        
}
```

I tried to reach the css file with `../css/blue-theme.css` and `/css/blue-theme.css` and `css/blue-theme.css` also `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/blue-theme.css`
What should I write in this case to get the correct path and make the script work online ? I've tried pretty much everything that I know but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try just "/wp-content/themes/theme1/css/blue-theme.css" the full relative path or try get_site_url(); before that.

Comment: The console does not reply a 404 error anymore. When I click on the theme changer, it switches to pink-theme to purple-theme (for example), so the main CSS file changes but when I open it in another tab, it redirects to a 404 not found. I think this is because the css file is not correctly called in my javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, that was such a simple problem, but also the last thing I could think of.

The path was `../themes/theme1/css` instead of `../themes/Theme1/css` .